# Открытие ссылки в новой вкладке, когда кликнувший по ней пользователь остаётся на прежней странице

Tags: html

Как реализовать открытие ссылки в новой вкладке, но только чтоб пользователь оставался на странице, где расположена эта ссылка?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<a href="" target="_blank">some link</a>`, а чтобы пользователь оставался на той же странице это он сам в браузере должен настроить перекидывать его на новую страницу или оставаться на текущей в настройках самого браузера

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего вы имеете ввиду:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Удерживать Ctrl при клике по ссылке. А открывать, как указано в ответах выше.

Answer (score 0):

Так же можно открывать ссылки в новых вкладках браузера нажав на них колёсиком мышки.